# Hide ACF from source code until a "show" button is clicked

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I am looking for a way to hide the content of an AFC (advanced custom field) on the front-end until the user clicks a "Show" Button.

I don't want to use CSS (display:none) approach. The ACF content should not appear on the source code of the page, it should only be loaded after the user clicks.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) the contents of the field(s) on a click.

In a nutshell:

In your page template

```
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;
?>
<button class="acf-get-content-button">Let's see that content</button>
<div id="acf-content-wrapper" data-id="<?php echo $post_id; ?>"></div>
```

JS

```
(function($) {
  $('.acf-get-content-button').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $contentWrapper = $( '#acf-content-wrapper' );
    var postId = $contentWrapper.data( 'id' );

    $.ajax({
      url: "/wp-content/plugins/my-custom-plugin/public/field-ajax.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        'post_id': postId
      },
    })
      .done(function( data ) {
        $contentWrapper.append( data );
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

field-ajax.php

```
<?php
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require_once('../../../../wp-load.php');

$post_id = $_POST["post_id"];
$content = get_field( 'field', $post_id );

echo $content;
```

This code will need customization for your use, so it'll take some more research on your part.

Note that I placed the ajax script inside a custom plugin. This is what I would recommend, but some security plugins (iThemes Security, at least) has the option to disable running PHP in the plugins folder, which would break this.

Comment: Hmm i am not sure this is what i was trying to do. The admin will put information on a wysiwig field on the back end editor and publish the post. Then the visitors will need to click a button to see it. Is this what this does?

Comment: That's not what this does, but it's the same idea. I'll change some things.

Comment: Ok, updated to retrieve a field value.

Comment: Ok i will try to implement this tomorrow and get back to you thanks!

Comment: Hm trying to do this gives me "HTTP ERROR 500". 
I am trying to hide just the get_field('download') not the entire page not sure if this does that. Where exactly the JS part has to be in the template? I put it below the acf-get-content-button

Comment: This does hide only the get_field(). The js should be enqueued ( wp_enqueue_script() ) in the footer as part of your theme or, if you made one, custom plugin. It should also work inside a <script> tag in your template though. Does the page load give a 500 error, or the ajax after you click returns a 500? You probably have an issue with your PHP syntax - either in the page template or the ajax.php.

Comment: Ok no more error now. The button shows up i changed the ajax $content = get_field( 'field', $post_id ); to the actual field i want. But when i click the button nothing happens, no error in console, nothing. What could it be? All codes are present.

Comment: Progress it works FINE when calling the ajax php directly and changing the post method to "REQUEST". But using POST method and clicking the show button does nothing.